# Laravel Passport Client Credentials Grant

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I use Laravel Passport for my API authentication. I have already set up a Password Credentials Grant and it works. Now I need a Client Credentials Grant for machine-to-machine authentication.

I created a new client with 
`php artisan passport:client --client`.
I tried to make a request to /oauth/token with this body (with Insomnia):

```
{
    "client_id":3,
    "secret":"wJWuVVydkHIQQ6gC7xvd0eEKytIFAD3pa149e6TR",
    "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}
```

That's the response i get from Passport:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
  "message": "Client authentication failed"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is an invalid client?
This is the entry in the oauth_clients table for my client, exported as json:

```
{
    "id":"3",
    "user_id":null,
    "name":"ClientCredentials Grant Client",
    "secret":"wJWuVVydkHIQQ6gC7xvd0eEKytIFAD3pa149e6TR",
    "redirect":"",
    "personal_access_client":"0",
    "password_client":"0",
    "revoked":"0",
    "created_at":"2019-04-30 17:06:17",
    "updated_at":"2019-04-30 17:06:17"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I feel a bit stupid...

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make. I posted as an answer so you can mark accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your request, the `secret` param should be `client_secret` instead.

From the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

[image]